# ERRO 1442 - Trigger AFTER INSERT - MySql

Tags: sql, trigger, mysql

O meu banco de Dados tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE BAIRRO
(
  BAI_COD INT(4) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  BAI_NOME VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_BAIRRO PRIMARY KEY(BAI_COD)
);

CREATE TABLE PAGAMENTO
(
    PAG_COD INT(2) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PAG_DESCRICAO VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PAGAMENTO PRIMARY KEY(PAG_COD)
);

CREATE TABLE FABRICANTE
(
    FAB_CNPJ VARCHAR(14)NOT NULL,
    FAB_NOME VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FABRICANTE PRIMARY KEY(FAB_CNPJ)
);

CREATE TABLE MODELO
(
    MOD_COD INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    MOD_NOME VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE,
    MOD_FABRICANTE VARCHAR(14)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MODELO PRIMARY KEY(MOD_COD),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FABRICANTE FOREIGN KEY(MOD_FABRICANTE)REFERENCES FABRICANTE(FAB_CNPJ)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE CARRO
(
    CAR_PLACA VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
    CAR_COR VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
    CAR_ANO INT(4) NOT NULL,
    CAR_STATUS VARCHAR(12)NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DISPONÍVEL',
    CAR_VALOR DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL ,
    CAR_MODELO INT(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CARRO PRIMARY KEY(CAR_PLACA),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MODELO FOREIGN KEY(CAR_MODELO)REFERENCES MODELO(MOD_COD)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE USUARIO
(
    USU_COD INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    USU_NOME VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL,
    USU_LOGIN VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    USU_SENHA VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_USUARIO PRIMARY KEY(USU_COD)
);


CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    CLI_CNH VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
    CLI_NOME VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL,
    CLI_FONE VARCHAR(11)NOT NULL,
    CLI_BAIRRO INT(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTE PRIMARY KEY(CLI_CNH),   
    CONSTRAINT FK_BAIRRO FOREIGN KEY(CLI_BAIRRO)REFERENCES BAIRRO(BAI_COD)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE LOCACAO
(
    LOC_COD INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    DTALUGUEL DATE NOT NULL,
    DTDEVOLUCAO DATE CHECK (DTDEVOLUCAO>=DTALUGUEL),
    VALORALOC DECIMAL(10,2),
    STATUS VARCHAR(7)NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ABERTO',
    QTDE_DIAS INT(5) NOT NULL,
    LOC_CLIENTE VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
    LOC_CARRO VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
    LOC_USUARIO INT(5) NOT NULL,
    LOC_PAGAMENTO INT(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_LOCACAO PRIMARY KEY(LOC_COD),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE FOREIGN KEY(LOC_CLIENTE)REFERENCES CLIENTE(CLI_CNH)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO FOREIGN KEY(LOC_CARRO)REFERENCES CARRO(CAR_PLACA)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY(LOC_USUARIO)REFERENCES USUARIO(USU_COD)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PAGAMENTO FOREIGN KEY(LOC_PAGAMENTO)REFERENCES PAGAMENTO(PAG_COD)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Insert que podem ser úteis para o teste

INSERT INTO fabricante(fab_cnpj, fab_nome) VALUES ('59275792000150', 'Chevrolet');

INSERT INTO modelo(mod_nome, mod_fabricante)VALUES ('Prisma Joy', '59275792000150');

INSERT INTO carro(car_placa, car_cor, car_ano, car_valor, car_modelo)
    VALUES ('HHKU1555', 'Prata', 2013, 1711.0, 1);

INSERT INTO cliente(cli_cnh, cli_nome, cli_bairro, cli_fone)
    VALUES ('5253696855', 'Otávio Rodrigues', 13, '92982454750');

INSERT INTO PAGAMENTO (PAG_DESCRICAO) VALUES ('Dinheiro');

INSERT INTO USUARIO(USU_NOME, USU_LOGIN, USU_SENHA)VALUES('MARIO BRÓS', 'MARIO', '123');  

INSERT INTO locacao(dtaluguel, qtde_dias, loc_cliente, loc_carro, loc_usuario, loc_pagamento)
    VALUES ('2018-02-21', 10, '5222222855','KIUS1290', 1, 1);
```

Minha ideia é a seguinte, após vincular um CARRO na LOCAÇÃO o valor de sua diária contida na coluna CAR_VALOR da tabela CARRO deve ser copiada para a coluna VALORALOC da tabela LOCACAO, e também, após esse CARRO ser vinculado nessa LOCAÇÃO, seu status que é representado pela coluna CAR_STATUS da tabela CARRO deverá ser atualizada para 'INDISPONÍVEL'.

Para isso eu criei duas triggers:

```
-- trigger 1


DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER atualizar_status_carro
      AFTER INSERT
      ON locacao
      FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN 
        UPDATE carro
        SET car_status = 'INDISPONÍVEL'
        WHERE CAR_PLACA = NEW.LOc_CARRO;        
    END$$
DELIMITER ;$$

-- trigger 2

    DELIMITER $
    CREATE TRIGGER inserir_valor_locacao
      AFTER INSERT
      ON locacao
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE locacao
        SET valoraloc = (select car_valor from carro where car_placa = NEW.loc_carro)
        WHERE loc_cod = NEW.loc_cod;        
    END$
    DELIMITER ;$
```

Após ter criado as triggers e tentar inserir a LOCACAO:

```
INSERT INTO locacao(dtaluguel, qtde_dias, loc_cliente, loc_carro, loc_usuario, loc_pagamento)
    VALUES ('2018-02-21', 10, '5222222855','HHKU1555', 1, 1);
```

Aparece esse erro, e minha dúvida é como eu poderia resolver este problema:
Erro:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'locacao' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.   0.063 sec
```

Comment: A trigger tem de ser de BEFORE e não precisa de UPDATE basta setar o new.<campo>.

Comment: Você se refere as duas trigger's?

Comment: Sim , e em tese bastaria uma.